# Is it correct to say that every one-to-one mapping is a bijection between its domain (preimage) and its image?

Tags: terminology, definition

To me this seems tautological.  But I've had someone challenge me on it.  Here $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers.

What I call the domain of a mapping is the set of all arguments for which there is a value of the mapping. For example, consider the mapping $f:\mathcal{D}\to{R}$ whith $f\left(x\right)\equiv\sqrt{x},$ and $x,f\left(x\right)\in{\mathbb{R}}$.  The domain of $f$ is $\mathcal{D}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\backepsilon x\ge 0\}$. The image (range) is $\mathcal{R}=f\left(\mathcal{D}\right)=\mathcal{D}.$  That is, the domain and image are identical. Since $f$ is monotonic, it is one-to-one.  Thereofore $f:\mathcal{D}\to{R}$ is a bijection.  The image and co-domain are identical.

On the other hand if $g\left(x\right)\equiv\sqrt{x},$ the mapping $g:\mathcal{D}\to{\mathbb{R}}$ is an injection, but not a bijection.  So the determination as to whether the mapping is a bijection depends on the specification of the co-domain.

The domain of the mapping is the same in both cases, and it is incorrect (but not too uncommon) to write $g:\mathbb{R}\to{\mathbb{R}}$ or $f:\mathbb{R}\to{\mathbb{R}}.$  The image of $g$ is still $\mathcal{R}.$

Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct. By definition, the map is surjective and hence bijective.

Comment: A mapping is and ordered triple (f,D,E)  where f:D ---> E .If the mapping is injective (1-1) and surjective (onto E ,meaning that the range is E )  then the mapping is called bijective .So what is your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "mostly correct" - there are two points to be made.

---

The first concerns function identity and your use of the word "is." **This is actually an important point.**

In many (most?) presentations, a function is determined by three pieces of data: its domain $D$, its codomain $C$, and the corresponding "graph" relation $\subseteq D\times C$ (namely, $\{(a,b): f(a)=b\}$). In this context, changing the codomain changes the function: e.g. $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto x^2$ is a different function from $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}: x\mapsto x^2$. And so the statement "every one-to-one mapping **is** a bijection between its domain and its image" would be technically incorrect. The right formulation of the obvious fact would be a bit more complicated - at the very least, one probably ought to say "yields" (or "induces," or etc.) instead of "is."

In other contexts - e.g. set theory - a function is determined entirely by (indeed, *is*) its graph $\{(a,b): f(a)=b\}$, and according to this approach your statement as phrased is correct.

---

The other issue concerns terminology - specifically, a terminological issue which arises if you phrase your question slightly differently *(and if you happened to phrase it differently in your conversation you mentioned, it could actually be relevant)*. **This isn't really important.**

The word *range* is (to my understanding) used to refer to the image in most modern texts, but some texts (such as [Munkres](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131816292)) use it to refer to the *codomain*. So if you had said "every one-to-one mapping is a bijection between its domain and its **range**," your interlocutor might object if they interpret "range" as "codomain."